# Add and Remove buttons don't work in premade Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, carousel, slick.js

I've been using the Slick carousel from here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started and it seems promising, but I'm having problems. I'm trying to use the "Add & Remove" demo, and while I've got it stylistically identical, the JS code for the buttons is not working.

Here's a fiddle of what I have (It has a bunch of external resources): http://jsfiddle.net/uqgh5j18/1/

Please let me know if you have any idea what is going awry here. Thank you!

HTML

```
<section id="features" class="blue">
            <div class="content">       
                <hr id="demos"/>
                <h2>Add & Remove</h2>
                <div class="slider add-remove">
                    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-add-slide">Add Slide</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-remove-slide">Remove Slide</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.add-remove').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });

    $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
        slideIndex++;
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','&lt;div&gt;&lt;h3&gt;' + slideIndex +
                               '&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
    });

    $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
        if (slideIndex !== 0){
            slideIndex--;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems that I saw on the console tab.

**First:**
`slideIndex` wasn't declared.

To fix add this:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
```

**Second:**

Syntax error on this line:

```
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','&lt;div&gt;&lt;h3&gt;' + slideIndex +
                               '&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
```

To fix that, change that to just:

```
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex +
                               '</h3></div>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqgh5j18/2/)

Comment: Yes! That explains it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @matthew Great! Glad it helped!